# Handling events in asp.net server control

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls

I have a custom asp.net server component that is rendered as below:

```
<div id="divContentRating">
<div id="divAskForRating">
    #Question
    <br />
    <a id="likeIcon"><img src="#PositiveRateIconPath"/></a>
    <a id="neutralIcon"><img src="#NeutralRateIconPath"/></a>
    <a id="unlikeIcon"><img src="#NegativeRateIconPath"/></a>
</div>
<div id="divPositiveRating">
    <div>
        <img src="#PositiveRateIconPath"/> #PositiveAnswerMessage <br />
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="updateRate">Güncelle</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="divNegativeRating">
    <div>
        <img src="#NegativeRateIconPath"/> #NegativeAnswerMessage <br />
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="updateRate">Güncelle</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="divNeutralRating">
    <div>
        <img src="#NeutralRateIconPath"/> #NeutralAnswerMessage <br />
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="updateRate">Güncelle</a>
    </div>
</div>

<input type="hidden" id="HasRated" value="#HasRated">
<input type="hidden" id="Rate" value="#Rate">
<input type="hidden" id="ContentKey" value="#ContentKey">
<input type="hidden" id="RatingId" value="#RatingId">
</div>
```

Is it possible to handle the click on the images in my web control? I mean, I want to do some operations when user clicks on the images, but I want to code these in my web control.

Here is my web control:

```
[DefaultProperty("ContentKey")]
[ToolboxData("<{0}:ContentRating runat=server></{0}:ContentRating>")]
public class ContentRating : WebControl
{
    [Bindable(true)]
    [Category("Appearance")]
    [DefaultValue("")]
    [Localizable(true)]
    public string ContentKey
    {
        get
        {
            String s = (String)ViewState["ContentKey"];
            return ((s == null) ? "[" + this.ID + "]" : s);
        }

        set
        {
            ViewState["ContentKey"] = value;
        }
    }

    [Bindable(true)]
    [Category("Appearance")]
    [DefaultValue("")]
    [Localizable(true)]
    public string PositiveRateIconPath
    {
        get
        {
            String s = (String)ViewState["PositiveRateIconPath"];
            return ((s == null) ? "[" + this.ID + "]" : s);
        }

        set
        {
            ViewState["PositiveRateIconPath"] = value;
        }
    }

    [Bindable(true)]
    [Category("Appearance")]
    [DefaultValue("")]
    [Localizable(true)]
    public string NegativeRateIconPath
    {
        get
        {
            String s = (String)ViewState["NegativeRateIconPath"];
            return ((s == null) ? "[" + this.ID + "]" : s);
        }

        set
        {
            ViewState["NegativeRateIconPath"] = value;
        }
    }

    [Bindable(true)]
    [Category("Appearance")]
    [DefaultValue("")]
    [Localizable(true)]
    public string NeutralRateIconPath
    {
        get
        {
            String s = (String)ViewState["NeutralRateIconPath"];
            return ((s == null) ? "[" + this.ID + "]" : s);
        }

        set
        {
            ViewState["NeutralRateIconPath"] = value;
        }
    }

    protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
    {
        ContentRatingSettings contentRatingSettings = GetContentRatingSettings(this.ContentKey);

        if (!contentRatingSettings.Visible)
        {
            output.Write(string.Empty);
            return;
        }

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(@"
<div id=""divContentRating"">
<div id=""divAskForRating"">#Question
    <br />
    <a id=""likeIcon""><img src=""#PositiveRateIconPath""/></a>
    <a id=""neutralIcon""><img src=""#NeutralRateIconPath""/></a>
    <a id=""unlikeIcon""><img src=""#NegativeRateIconPath""/></a>
</div>
<div id=""divPositiveRating"">
    <div>
        <img src=""#PositiveRateIconPath""/> #PositiveAnswerMessage <br />
        <a href=""javascript:void(0)"" class=""updateRate"">Güncelle</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id=""divNegativeRating"">
    <div>
        <img src=""#NegativeRateIconPath""/> #NegativeAnswerMessage <br />
        <a href=""javascript:void(0)"" class=""updateRate"">Güncelle</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id=""divNeutralRating"">
    <div>
        <img src=""#NeutralRateIconPath""/> #NeutralAnswerMessage <br />
        <a href=""javascript:void(0)"" class=""updateRate"">Güncelle</a>
    </div>
</div>

<input type=""hidden"" id=""HasRated"" value=""#HasRated"">
<input type=""hidden"" id=""Rate"" value=""#Rate"">
<input type=""hidden"" id=""ContentKey"" value=""#ContentKey"">
<input type=""hidden"" id=""RatingId"" value=""#RatingId"">

<script type=""text/javascript"">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var protocol = location.protocol;
    var host = window.location.host;

    if ($(""#HasRated"").val() == ""True"")
    {
        var rate = $(""#Rate"").val();
        if (rate == 1) {
            setPositiveRatedView();
        }
        else if (rate == 0) {
            setNeutralRatedView();
        }
        else if (rate == -1) {
            setNegativeRatedView();
        }
        else {
            setNotRatedView();
        }
    }
    else {
        setNotRatedView();
    }

    $(""#likeIcon"").click(function () {
        alert(""like"");
        setPositiveRatedView();
        ratePage(1, """");
    });

    $(""#neutralIcon"").click(function () {
        alert(""neutral"");
        setNeutralRatedView();
        ratePage(0, """");
    });

    $(""#unlikeIcon"").click(function () {
        alert(""unlike"");
        setNegativeRatedView();
        //mkMPopClc('NegativeRatingReason', 200, 300, 0, 0);
    });

    $("".updateRate"").click(function () {
        setNotRatedView();
    });

    function setNotRatedView() {
        $(""#divNeutralRating"").fadeOut();
        $(""#divPositiveRating"").fadeOut();
        $(""#divAskForRating"").fadeIn();
        $(""#divNegativeRating"").fadeOut();
    }

    function setPositiveRatedView()
    {
        $(""#divNegativeRating"").fadeOut();
        $(""#divNeutralRating"").fadeOut();
        $(""#divAskForRating"").fadeOut();
        $(""#divPositiveRating"").fadeIn();
    }

    function setNegativeRatedView() {
        $(""#divNeutralRating"").fadeOut();
        $(""#divPositiveRating"").fadeOut();
        $(""#divAskForRating"").fadeOut();
        $(""#divNegativeRating"").fadeIn();
    }

    function setNeutralRatedView() {
        $(""#divNegativeRating"").fadeOut();
        $(""#divPositiveRating"").fadeOut();
        $(""#divAskForRating"").fadeOut();
        $(""#divNeutralRating"").fadeIn();
    }

    function ratePage(rating, comment)
    {
        //alert(rating + """" """" + comment);
        var contentKey = $(""#ContentKey"").val();
        var hasRated = $(""#HasRated"").val();
        var ratingId = $(""#RatingId"").val();

        }
        });
        </script>
        </div>");

        SetTrackingCookie();

        builder.Replace("#ContentKey", this.ContentKey);
        builder.Replace("#PositiveRateIconPath", this.PositiveRateIconPath);
        builder.Replace("#NeutralRateIconPath", this.NeutralRateIconPath);
        builder.Replace("#NegativeRateIconPath", this.NegativeRateIconPath);
        builder.Replace("#Question", contentRatingSettings.Question);
        builder.Replace("#PositiveAnswerMessage", contentRatingSettings.PositiveAnswerMessage);
        builder.Replace("#NeutralAnswerMessage", contentRatingSettings.NeutralAnswerMessage);
        builder.Replace("#NegativeAnswerMessage", contentRatingSettings.NegativeAnswerMessage);

        output.Write(builder);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I suggest you step back and re-read on the basics of web apps and how ASP.NET approaches them. There are basically two ways to do this, by having the image be a link that initiates a *postback* that will trigger a full page reload, with your event handler running at some point thereof. Or an AJAX-based *partial postback* that will do much of the same but instead of reloading the whole page refresh the contents of a given set of controls.

Comment: For starters, you can wrap the image in an `<asp:LinkButton>` and handle the `Click` or `Command` events, or a `<button runat="server">` and handle `ServerClick`. (The former seems more appropriate for a full postback, the latter for an AJAX call since it doesn't really link anywhere, but they're mostly interchangeable for this purpose.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to attach events to controls, overriding `CompositeControl` will be a lot easier than `WebControl`.

CreateChildControl can route the event to its child but WebControl can't.

Please keep it mind that it is an alternative approach to your question because it requires some of changes (from your original code).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do, the quickest option will be to add `runat="server"` tag to the image control along with an on click event handler than points to a function.

This will perform a postback to the asp page whenever the image is clicked.

If the post back is not desired then you will need to wire up javascript to do an ajax based postback and appropriate client/server handlers.